# Questions about table.insert

Tags: lua

I have a problem understanding table.insert in Lua.
Referring to Wrox Beginning Lua Programming book page 129,

```
 --A demonstration of sorting an associative table.
 NameToInstr = {John = “rhythm guitar”,
 Paul = “bass guitar”,
 George = “lead guitar”,
 Ringo = “drumkit”}

 --Transfer the associative table NameToInstr to the
 --array Sorted:
 Sorted = {}
 for Name, Instr in pairs(NameToInstr) do
 table.insert(Sorted, {Name = Name, Instr = Instr})
 end

 --The comparison function sorts by Name:
 table.sort(Sorted, function(A, B) return A.Name < B.Name end)

 --Output:
 for _, NameInstr in ipairs(Sorted) do
 print(NameInstr.Name .. “ played “ .. NameInstr.Instr)
 end
```

and my questions will be..

1. Why do we need to do the Name = Name and Instr = Instr assignment?
2. Why those assignment need to be put inside those "table constructor"?
3. In "-- The comparison function sorts by Name:", How does the "function (A, B)" works since A and B are not assigned to any value previously

Many thanks in advance..(sorry for my poor English)

Answer (score 0):

[`table.insert`](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#pdf-table.insert) is used for array-like tables; that is, tables with keys from 1 to n. It inserts a value at a specified integer index and shifts the rest of the array downwards.

```
local t = {1, 2, 3}
table.insert(t, 2, "foo") -- t = {1, "foo", 2, 3}
table.insert(t, "bar")    -- t = {1, "foo", 2, 3, "bar"}
```

In your example, the code is creating an array of tables, where each table has a `Name` and an `Instr` field. `table.insert` is simply appending each array entry to the end of the array.

Answer (score 0):

1. Why do we need to do the Name = Name and Instr = Instr assignment?

   A: The part on the left of the assignment is the field name, the part on the right is the value to associate. The statement `t={a=123, b=var}` associates a field `a` in `t` with value 123, and associates a field `b` in that table with the value of a variable called `var` (unless `var` is itself a table, then `b` is associated with a reference to the table that `var` identifies but this is a separate issue that is not directly related to your question). So in your case it just so happens that the developer sets the keys to have the same name as the `for` loop variables.
2. Why those assignment need to be put inside those "table constructor"?

   A: Not sure what you mean by "table constructor", where do you see that?
3. In "-- The comparison function sorts by Name:", How does the "function (A, B)" works since A and B are not assigned to any value previously

   A: The `sort` function will call the anonymous function many times while sorting, each time with two values, one for A and one for B, expecting a return value indicating whether A is smaller than B for the given pair.

Comment: what I mean about the table constructor are the curly braces that wraps around "Name = Name" and "Instr = Instr"

Comment: @Boodew `function(A, B)`...`end` is a function definition, much like a table constructor. Each time it is executed, a function value is created. `A` and `B` are the formal parameters. `table.sort` takes a function value as its second parameter, with the expectation that the function will compare two parameter values as specified in its [documentation](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#pdf-table.sort).